Dice Problem (Recurrence Solution) - why is my method slightly off?
Suppose we roll a fair dice $n$ times. What is the probability of a run of at least $x$ sixes?
My approach to this was to define a recurrence relation. There are two ways to get a run of length $x$ sixes in $n+1$ rolls: either you get a run of length $x$ in the first $n$ rolls, or you get a run in the last $x$ rolls of $n+1$ rolls (and no run before).
Therefore P(run of $x$ sixes in $n+1$ rolls) = P($x$ sixes in $n$ rolls) + P(run in the last $x$ rolls of $n+1$ rolls and no run before).
P(run in the last $x$ rolls of $n+1$ rolls and no run before) = P(no run in the first $n-x$ rolls) * P(no $6$ on the $n-x+1th$ roll) * P(last $x$ rolls are all $6$).
So, P(run of $x$ sixes in $n+1$ rolls) = P($x$ sixes in $n$ rolls) + P(no run in the first $n-x$ rolls) * P(no $6$ on the $n-x+1th$ roll) * P(last $x$ rolls of $n+1$ are all $6$)
The official solution does the exact same methodology, but states that the probability I calculated is actually equal to P(run of at least $x$ sixes in $n+1$ rolls, as opposed to P(run of exactly $x$ sixes in $n+1$ rolls). Why would this probability be at least, as opposed to exactly?


If the last $x$ rolls of $n+1$ rolls are successes, then the length of the last run can be either $x$ or $x+1, x+2, ... $, where the latter means that there is a run of length $x$ in the first $n$ rolls, overlapping with the first part $p_n$ of the recurrence. Hence, we need to make sure that the length of the last run is exactly $x$.

Thanks @Amir, I'm not sure I follow. Isn't the P(no 6
on the n-x+1 roll) eliminating any possibility of runs greater than length x (that terminate at n+1)?

The reason is that the event $P(\text{run of $x$ sixes in the first $n$ rolls})$ includes cases where there is a run of $x+1$ sixes.
Let $n=10$ and $x=3$. Consider this run of $n+1=11$ rolls.
$$
\color{blue}{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,6,6,6},6\tag{$*$}
$$
This is one of the outcomes included in $P(\text{run of $x$ sixes in the first $n$ rolls})$. However, the fact that the run of sixes occurred at the very end, plus the fact that the $(n+1)^\text{st}$ roll was a six, implies that this outcome actually has a run of $4$ sixes, not just $3$. Therefore, your counting method includes sequences which have a run of more than $x$ sixes.

For fun, let $q_n$ be the probability of getting a run of exactly $x$ sixes in $n$ rolls, and let us try to find what the recurrence for $q_{n+1}$ is. I will give a detailed explanation of how I found the solution first. At the end, I give a intuitive explanation.
Just like before, there are two cases. Either a run of sixes occurs somewhere before the very end, or it only occurs at the very end. The probability for the latter case is $(1-q_{n-x})\cdot (1/6)^x\cdot (5/6)$, just like before. However, we need to be careful when calculating the probability of an earlier run of $x$ sixes occurring. Consider the length of the run of sixes at the end of the string, and call its length $y$. It is possible to have $y=0$, which occurs when the last roll is not a six. To find the probability of a run of $x$ sixes occurring before the end, we sum over all possible lengths of this end run, times the probability of a run of exactly $y$ sixes at the end, times the probability of an earlier run of sixes happening.
$$
q_{n+1}=(1/6)^x\cdot (5/6)\cdot(1-q_{n-x})+\sum_{y=0}^{n-x}(1/6)^y\cdot (5/6)\cdot q_{n-y}\tag1
$$
We can turn this into a finite order recurrence as follows. Consider the above equation with $n-1$ substituted for $n$.
$$
q_{n}=(1/6)^x\cdot (5/6)\cdot(1-q_{n-1-x})+\sum_{y=0}^{n-1-x}(1/6)^y\cdot (5/6)\cdot q_{n-1-y}
$$
After re-indexing, and simplifying, the becomes
$$
q_{n}=(1/6)^x\cdot (5/6)\cdot(1-q_{n-1-x})-5q_n+6\sum_{y=0}^{n-x}(1/6)^y\cdot (5/6)\cdot q_{n-y}\tag2
$$
Finally, we shall subtract $(1/6)$ times equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$. As a result, the two summations in these equations perfectly cancel, leaving a finite order recurrence.
$$
q_{n+1}-\tfrac16 q_n=
(\tfrac16)^x\cdot \tfrac56\cdot(1-q_{n-x})
-(\tfrac16)^{x+1}\cdot \tfrac56\cdot(1-q_{n-1-x})
+\tfrac56 q_n
$$
This simplifies to
$$
\boxed{q_{n+1}=q_n+(\tfrac16)^x\cdot \tfrac56\cdot(1-q_{n-x})-\color{#a00}{(\tfrac16)^{x+1}\cdot \tfrac56\cdot(1-q_{n-1-x})}}
$$
This now resembles the original recurrence, $p_{n+1}=p_n+(1-p_{n-x})(\tfrac16)^x\cdot \tfrac56$,  very closely. The only difference is the $\color{#a00}{\text{red}}$ correction term. I believe the effect of this correction term is that we are subtracting all of the "bad" cases represented by $(*)$ in the first section of my answer. Since these are the only bad cases, subtracting them out gives the correct recurrence.

Thank you @Mike Earnest. If I were to proceed with my method of counting runs of exactly length x, could I then multiply P( sixes in  rolls) * 5/6 to account for having no 6 at the x+1th roll?
Then, my recurrence would be:
P(run of  sixes in +1 rolls) = P( sixes in  rolls) *5/6 + P(run in the last  rolls of +1 rolls and no run before)

@mk0219 No, that does not work, either. Because now you are excluding cases like $6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6$, but these are OK to include. The recurrence for exactly $x$ sixes is just a bit trickier, I might edit my answer to include it when I figure it out.

@mk0219 I have edited my answer with the "run of exactly x sixes" recurrence.

Thank you, I appreciate it.
